# WPF MDi With Background Element

Tags: wpf, mdi

How can add Elements inside wpf MDIcontainer section(Like background).[image]

I need this

Comment: question is not clear, please add more details.

Comment: How can add Elements inside wpf MDI container section?

Comment: You seems to be a winforms guy, I think following link may help you with WPF: http://wpftutorial.net/LearnWPFin14Days.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a DataGrid for your MDI. Bind an ObservableCollection as its ItemSource. Then you can add a new Employee to that Collection. If INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented correctly it will AutoUpdate your Collection and the Content will be shown.

**NOTE:** Your Employee window has **NOT** to be shown via .ShowDialog() cause this will freeze the background Window.

This is no problem at all when hitting the save button is closing your employee window.

Comment: But MDI container not supporting child elements